# How to extract decoded jwt value integer value

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, singleton

How to extract JWT code

jwt.claim(name: "role_id").integer

```
 po jwt.claim(name: "role_id")
▿ Claim
  ▿ value : Optional<Any>
    - some : 1
```

When on print It gives Optional value.
When assign to Int variable the value not assigning and return nil.

Assign Value to singleton

```
      if let jti = jwt.claim(name: "jti").string{
                SharedManager.shared.jti = jti. // it worked.
            }
      if let roleId = jwt.claim(name: "role_id").integer {
         SharedManager.shared.roleId = roleId // it not working.
       }
```

Singletone class

```
class SharedManager
{
    static let shared: SharedManager = SharedManager()
    var jti = String()
    var roleID = Int()
}
```

Comment: What's the library you're using? What's the code of `.integer`?Because `jwt.claim(name: "role_id")` is `Any`, not an `Int`, so it depend on how `integer` works behind the scene.

Comment: the library I used was -> pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 2.6' https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift

Comment: the value in integer is 1

Comment: You said "it no working", so I guess that you don't enter the `if let roleId = jwt.claim(name: "role_id").integer {` if? So that `integer` fails, no?

Comment: @Larme for integer it fails, no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: Could be interesting to get: `jwt.claim(name: "role_id").rawValue as? String`, and and maybe its length?: `jwt.claim(name: "role_id").rawValue as? String).count`? Why for instance, Int(" 1") or Int("1 ") (with spaces) fails... And/or breakpoint inside https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift/blob/master/JWTDecode/JWTDecode.swift to see which one of the line is triggered and the values in `.integer` call...

Comment: @Larme It works jwt.claim(name: "role_id").rawValue as? Int